Explode hive table with null arrays in the column
I have a below table which has 5 columns. The column CLASS have data with empty arrays.



key
arrival
carrier
class
departure




50B1AE7A0C1BF0001521CEE
["2024-02-15T11:35:00.000+08:00","2024-02-20T15:10:00.000+08:00"]
["MU","MU"]
[ ]
["2024-02-15T08:45:00.000+08:00","2024-02-20T12:35:00.000+08:00"]


0B88E4801F1B1000544C097
["2024-07-25T09:00:00.000+04:00","2024-08-08T07:30:00.000+02:00"]
["TX","TX"]
["T","X"]
["2024-07-24T19:55:00.000+02:00","2024-08-07T22:10:00.000+04:00"]


AC3668A4A61C800015210B6
["2024-04-08T20:40:00.000+03:00","2024-04-09T02:59:00.000+03:00","2024-06-29T06:40:00.000+03:00","2024-06-29T13:35:00.000+01:00"]
["MS","MS","MS","MS"]
["T","T"]
["2024-04-08T15:00:00.000+01:00","2024-04-08T23:40:00.000+03:00","2024-06-29T04:00:00.000+03:00","2024-06-29T10:10:00.000+03:00"]


86BF7C03C222300004DE0EE
["2024-01-21T22:35:00.000+06:00"]
["BG"]
[ ]
["2024-01-21T21:15:00.000+05:30"]



I am expecting the data in below format:



key
arrival
carrier
class
departure




50B1AE7A0C1BF0001521CEE
2024-02-15T11:35:00.000+08:00
MU
null
2024-02-15T08:45:00.000+08:00


50B1AE7A0C1BF0001521CEE
2024-02-20T15:10:00.000+08:00
MU
null
2024-02-20T12:35:00.000+08:00


0B88E4801F1B1000544C097
2024-07-25T09:00:00.000+04:00
TX
T
2024-07-24T19:55:00.000+02:00


0B88E4801F1B1000544C097
2024-08-08T07:30:00.000+02:00
TX
X
2024-08-07T22:10:00.000+04:00


AC3668A4A61C800015210B6
2024-04-08T20:40:00.000+03:00
MS
T
2024-04-08T15:00:00.000+01:00


AC3668A4A61C800015210B6
2024-04-09T02:59:00.000+03:00
MS
T
2024-04-08T23:40:00.000+03:00


AC3668A4A61C800015210B6
2024-06-29T06:40:00.000+03:00
MS
T
2024-06-29T04:00:00.000+03:00


AC3668A4A61C800015210B6
2024-06-29T13:35:00.000+01:00
MS
T
2024-06-29T10:10:00.000+03:00


86BF7C03C222300004DE0EE
2024-01-21T22:35:00.000+06:00
BG
null
2024-01-21T21:15:00.000+05:30



I have tried multiple approaches but everytime it does a crossjoin with all the rows. Can someone please help me to get the required output

Try this. It will work.
select 
f.key,
exploded_arrival_table.exploded_arrival_col,
exploded_carrier_table.exploded_carrier_col,
exploded_class_table.exploded_class_col,
exploded_departure_table.exploded_departure_col 
from (select key, arrival, carrier, 
             CASE WHEN size(class)=0 and sz=1 THEN array("NULL") 
                  WHEN size(class)=0 and sz=2 THEN array("NULL","NULL")
                  WHEN size(class)=0 and sz=3 THEN array("NULL","NULL","NULL") 
                  WHEN size(class)=0 and sz=4 THEN array("NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL") 
                  ELSE class END AS class, 
       departure from (select *, size(arrival) as sz flight) in_tbl_flight) f 
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(f.arrival)   exploded_arrival_table as t_xat, exploded_arrival_col 
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(f.carrier)   exploded_carrier_table as t_xct, exploded_carrier_col
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(f.class)     exploded_class_table as  t_xcct, exploded_class_col
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(f.departure) exploded_departure_table as t_xdct, exploded_departure_col 
where t_xat=t_xct and t_xct=t_xcct and t_xcct=t_xdct;

